# SQL - Looking for a specific name without going through all the table

Tags: sql

There is a student table and you are looking for all the students having a particular name.

How to do it without going through the whole table?

How would you approach this kind of question? please add complexity

Comment: `select * from student where name = 'Arthur Dent'`;

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in SQL.  First, you just write the query as:

```
select s.*
from students s
where s.name = ?;
```

SQL then offers two methods for optimizing such a query.  By far the most common is to use an index:

```
create index idx_students_name on students(name);
```

There may be other ways to create effectively the same index as well.  This will speed the query directly.  However, on a small table, some databases might not use the index, because they calculate that a sequential scan is more efficient.

Another method is to partition the table by `name`.  This is really only common on very large tables and the partitioning key is typically a date/time value.

Remember:  SQL is a *descriptive* language not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query describes the result set.  The optimization phase determines what exact steps the engine takes to arrive at the result set.